# How to show layout to RecyclerView endless in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, gson

I want to load data from server and show in my application (`RecyclerView`), for this job, when the application starts it shows 10 posts and when scrolling `recyclerView` show another post .

I write below codes but when get other 10 posts, **not show** loading layout! I want when get other 10 posts, first **show loading** layout then show other 10 **posts**!

For connect to internet I use **`Retrofit v2`** and for custom `Endless` methos for `recyclerView` I use this class : [EndLess Class](https://gist.github.com/ssinss/e06f12ef66c51252563e#file-endlessrecycleronscrolllistener-java)

**My Activity codes:**

```
public class Category_page extends AppCompatActivity implements ConnectivityReceiver.ConnectivityReceiverListener {

    private static final long RIPPLE_DURATION = 250;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private TextView toolbar_title;
    private ImageView toolbar_menuImage;
    private Button categoryCheckNet_button;
    private RelativeLayout root;
    private CategoryAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView cat_recyclerView;
    private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    private RelativeLayout loadLayout, checkNetLayout;
    private String catTitle = "";
    private Integer catID;
    private Bundle bundle;
    private int pageCount = 1;
    private Context context;

    private List<R_CatModel> models;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.category_page);

        // Hide StatusBar color
        getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Initializing
        context = Category_page.this;
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.category_toolbar);
        cat_recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.category_recycler);
        toolbar_title = (TextView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_title);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        root = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_root);
        loadLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_empty_layout);
        checkNetLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.category_checkInternet_layout);
        categoryCheckNet_button = (Button) checkNetLayout.findViewById(R.id.checkNet_button);
        // Toolbar
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setTitle("");
        }

        // Receive Data
        bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        catID = bundle.getInt("categoryID");
        if (bundle != null) {
            catTitle = bundle.getString("categoryTitle");
        }
        if (catTitle != null) {
            toolbar_title.setText(catTitle);
        }

        // Load Data
        loadData();

        // Load Progress
        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Menu
        View guillotineMenu = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.menu_layout, null);
        root.addView(guillotineMenu);
        toolbar_menuImage = (ImageView) toolbar.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_pages_logo);
        new GuillotineAnimation.GuillotineBuilder(guillotineMenu, guillotineMenu.findViewById(R.id.menu_layout_image), toolbar_menuImage)
                .setStartDelay(RIPPLE_DURATION)
                .setActionBarViewForAnimation(toolbar)
                .setClosedOnStart(true)
                .build();
        // RecyclerView
        cat_recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        cat_recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        cat_recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener(mLayoutManager) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int current_page) {

                Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
                Call<R_CatModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getCatMoreResponse(catID, current_page);

                call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {

                        if (response != null) {
                            mAdapter.addNewItem(response.body().getCat_posts());
                            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        } else {
                            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            TastyToast.makeText(context, "خطایی رخ داده است", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    private void loadData() {
        boolean isConnected = ConnectivityReceiver.isConnected();

        retrofitData(isConnected);
    }

    private void retrofitData(boolean isConnect) {

        if (isConnect) {
            Retrofit_ApiInterface apiInterface = Retrofit_ApiClient.getClient().create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);
            Call<R_CatModelResponse> call = apiInterface.getCatResponse(catID);

            call.enqueue(new Callback<R_CatModelResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Response<R_CatModelResponse> response) {

                    if (response != null) {
                        models = response.body().getCat_posts();

                        mAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(context, cat_recyclerView, models);
                        cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                        loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    } else {
                        //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TastyToast.makeText(context, "خطایی رخ داده است", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                    }

                    checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<R_CatModelResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                    //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //TastyToast.makeText(context, "لطفا برنامه را مجددا باز کنید", TastyToast.LENGTH_LONG, TastyToast.ERROR);
                    Toast.makeText(Category_page.this, "Error 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //Cat_EmptyLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    Log.e("CatResponseError", "Error : " + t);

                }
            });
        } else {
            //loadLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            checkNetLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (mAdapter != null) {
                mAdapter.clear();
                cat_recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
            categoryCheckNet_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    loadData();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public void post_back(View view) {
        onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // register connection status listener
        MyApplication.getInstance().setConnectivityListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNetworkConnectionChanged(boolean isConnected) {
        retrofitData(isConnected);
    }
}
```

**My Adapter codes:**

```
public class CategoryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

    private List<R_CatModel> mDateSet;
    private Context mContext;

    private final int VIEW_ITEM = 1;
    private final int VIEW_PROG = 0;

    // The minimum amount of items to have below your current scroll position
    // before loading more.
    private int visibleThreshold = 10;
    private int lastVisibleItem, totalItemCount;
    private boolean loading;
    private OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener;

    public CategoryAdapter(Context context, RecyclerView recyclerView, List<R_CatModel> dataSet) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mDateSet = dataSet;

        if (recyclerView.getLayoutManager() instanceof LinearLayoutManager) {

            final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView
                    .getLayoutManager();
            recyclerView
                    .addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,
                                               int dx, int dy) {
                            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                            totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                            lastVisibleItem = linearLayoutManager
                                    .findLastVisibleItemPosition();
                            if (!loading
                                    && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                                // End has been reached
                                // Do something
                                if (onLoadMoreListener != null) {
                                    onLoadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
                                }
                                loading = true;
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return mDateSet.get(position) != null ? VIEW_ITEM : VIEW_PROG;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;
        if (viewType == VIEW_ITEM) {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.post_card_layout, parent, false);

            vh = new DataViewHolder(v);
        } else {
            View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                    R.layout.progressbar_item, parent, false);

            vh = new ProgressViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if (holder instanceof DataViewHolder) {
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getTitle()));

            Glide.with(mContext)
                    .load(mDateSet.get(position).getThumbnail_images().getMedium().getUrl())
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.post_image)
                    .crossFade()
                    .override(600, 350)
                    .into(((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image);

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_content.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getContent()));

            // Convert Date ////////
            String date = mDateSet.get(position).getDate();
            String[] parts = date.split(" ");
            String datePart = parts[0];
            String timePart = parts[1];

            int year;
            int month;
            int day;

            String[] dateParts = datePart.split("-");
            year = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[0]);
            month = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[1]);
            day = Integer.parseInt(dateParts[2]);

            JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate georgianDate = new JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate(year, month, day);
            JalaliCalendar.YearMonthDate JalaliDate = JalaliCalendar.gregorianToJalali(georgianDate);
            String jalaliDateTime = JalaliDate.toString();

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_dateTime.setText(jalaliDateTime);
            ////////////////////////

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_author.setText(Html.fromHtml(mDateSet.get(position).getCatAuthor().getAuthorName()));
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_author.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    R_CatModel model = mDateSet.get(position);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Profile_page.class));
                    //.putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                    //.putExtra("authorID", model.getAuthorID())
                    //.putExtra("authorStatus", model.getAuthorStatus()));
                }
            });

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setText(Html.fromHtml(String.valueOf(mDateSet.get(position).getCategories().get(0).getCatTitle())));
            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_category.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

            ((DataViewHolder) holder).main_post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int pos = holder.getPosition();
                    R_CatModel model = mDateSet.get(pos);
                    v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), PostShow_page.class)
                            .putExtra("title", model.getTitle())
                            .putExtra("image", model.getThumbnail())
                            .putExtra("content", model.getContent())
                            .putExtra("dateTime", model.getDate())
                            //.putExtra("author", model.getAuthor())
                            .putExtra("category", model.getTitle()));

                }
            });

        } else {
            ((ProgressViewHolder) holder).progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    public void setLoaded() {
        loading = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDateSet.size();
    }

    public void setOnLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener onLoadMoreListener) {
        this.onLoadMoreListener = onLoadMoreListener;
    }

    public void remove(int position) {
        mDateSet.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }

    public void clear() {
        mDateSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addNewItem(List<R_CatModel> newContent) {
        int start = this.mDateSet.size();//contents is a List of your items initialize it your constructor
        int end = newContent.size();
        mDateSet.addAll(newContent);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(start + 1, end);
    }


    public void add(List<R_CatModel> models) {
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void update(List<R_CatModel> models) {
        mDateSet.clear();
        mDateSet.addAll(models);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class DataViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView main_post_title, main_post_content, main_dateTime, main_author, main_category;
        private ImageView main_post_image;

        public DataViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            main_post_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_title);
            main_post_image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_picture_image);
            main_post_content = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_content_text);
            main_dateTime = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_date_text);
            main_author = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_name_text);
            main_category = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.post_category_text);
        }
    }

    public static class ProgressViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public AVLoadingIndicatorView progressBar;

        public ProgressViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            progressBar = (AVLoadingIndicatorView) v.findViewById(R.id.avloadingIndicatorView);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I show loading layout when get other 10 posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain you a simple way to solve this issue:

1- Put Linear `progressBar` below you `RecyclerView` which visibility by default is `gone`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/layout_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/gray_lightest">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/lv_paging"
        style="@style/RecycleView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="4dp"
        android:paddingTop="4dp"
        tools:listitem="@layout/row_list_base" />

    <com.rey.material.widget.ProgressView
        android:id="@+id/pvl_loading"
        style="@style/LinearProgress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

2- In your `onLoadMore` change visibility of `ProgressBar` to `Visible`:

```
 scrollListener = new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager()) {
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page) {
                progressBar.setVisiblity(View.VISIBLE);
                callWebService(page);
            }
        };
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(scrollListener);
```

3- When your request finish change visibility to `gone`:

```
public void onResponse(Call<YOUR_OBJECT> call, Response<YOUR_OBJECT> response) {     
                progressBar.setVisiblity(View.GONE);
                processResponse(response);
            }
```

**Alternative way**: If you want to handle progressBar in your Adapter see complete code [here](https://github.com/frogermcs/InstaMaterial/blob/master/app/src/main/java/io/github/froger/instamaterial/ui/adapter/FeedAdapter.java). Main key part of the code:

1- Add `showLoadingView` method to adapter:

```
 public void showLoadingView() {
        showLoadingView = true;
        notifyItemChanged(0);
    }
```

2- change `getViewType` to:

```
@Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (showLoadingView && position == 0) {
            return VIEW_TYPE_LOADER;
        } else {
            return VIEW_TYPE_DEFAULT;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always hold this layout as an item at the end of your list,
for example check

```
if (position = dataList.size-1) //it means we are at the end of list
    add your loading layout as an item in recyclerView
```

by this trick,loading layout always become your endless item in recyclerView and when you scroll down,you first see your loading layout,then other post add at the end ,and again your loading layout go at the end of the list.

Comment: or another trick is to add this layout at the bottom of your recyclerView in related xml,and visible/invisible it when get at the end of list

Comment: can you send me code? I am amateur, can you send me  code? please

Comment: sorry I'm busy these days and working on two project,but maybe can help you next week:)